# A bug rendering top bar in IE 9, started Dec 10, rep, dropdown, search pushed below bar

Tags: bug, status-norepro, internet-explorer-9

The top bar is not rendering correctly for me in IE 9. Uploading screen shots is blocked here, but everything to the right of my profile image is pushed down below the topbar (rep, menus, searchbox etc.). Was OK originally, broke yesterday (10 dec 2013).

Additional:

I am seeing this problem on stackoverflow and meta but not avp, mathematics or programmers.

Comment: do you have the link to your screenshot

Comment: I can't repro this in IE...but without a screenshot I don't know what you mean by "broke" either :-/

Comment: Sorry I know it's totally rubbish, but I'm in a bank and can't get a screenshot out. As below, seems to be OK now - since I've cleared my cache it doesn't repro.

Comment: you can see message of revision time "rev 2013.12.11.1749" in footer page.

Answer (score 3):

This may be a caching issue. stackoverflow and meta were sites I had visited since top bar was released, others were not.

Nuking cookies, and temp files in IE fixed the issue.

Comment: Making this as no-repro since it was isolated and a cache clear fixed it for you.  I have to assume your proxy had a dodge cache or something in play.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll post back if it reoccurs, thanks.