# Why is there no last activity message?

Tags: support, edits, last-activity

I can't see the 'last activity' field after editing my question.

I mean the field on the right-hand-side that lists your question as *active today*, *active yesterday* , *active 2 days ago*, etc.

[image]

As you can see there is no such field on [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18653144/whats-wrong-with-my-template-code).

But there is such a field on [other questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211057/a-bug-rendering-top-bar-in-ie-9-started-dec-10-rep-dropdown-search-pushed-be):

[image]

Can anyone tell me why it isn't there? Is this a bug perhaps?

Comment: I had tested on another computer !

Comment: What is 'active duration', exactly? Do you have an example of a question that has what you are missing here?

Comment: @Richard Tingle I mean as "Active today , Active yesterday , Active 2 days ago ....etc"

Comment: That only shows up if there are answers as well.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters do you mean like that "this message will appear after getting one comment or an answer " ?

Comment: @Cataclysm: Since your question here had comments but no such link, I corrected my statement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The 'activity' field only shows up if there are multiple posts on the page. In other words, only when there are *answers* will there be a 'active: *relative or absolute date*' entry on the right-hand side.

This field is there to help you home in on *which* of the posts (the question or one of the answers) last changed.

Take your question here for example. Before I posted this answer, there was no 'active' field present. Now that I posted it, the field showed up. The same applies to the sample question you linked to; there is an answer on that question too.